# Timer never stops

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I call [`Stop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.stop(v=vs.110).aspx) from [`Tick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx) callback event function but it doesn't stop and that function run over and over. Why is and how do I fix this?

This function is called once only:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
void foo() {
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timerTick);
    timer1.Start();
}
```

and the callback function:

```
 void timerTick(object o, EventArgs ea)
 {
     if (browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("stop it!");
         timer1.Stop();
     }
 }
```

This is going to show an infinity of `stop it` Messages Boxes while it must be show once.

Comment: How long did you leave the message box up before closing it?

Comment: Try putting the `timer1.Stop();` before the message box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reverse your statements:

```
if (browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
   timer1.Stop();
   MessageBox.Show("stop it!");
}
```

As it stands; it will keep ticking until you close a box (since `MessageBox.Show` blocks), which could be a *lot* of ticks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is use a `System.Timers.Timer` instead. You can tell that timer to run once and not restart until you tell it to.

```
System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
void foo() {    
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timerTick);

    //This assumes that the class `foo` is in is a System.Forms class. Makes the callback happen on the UI thread.
    timer1.SynchronizingObject = this;

    //Tells it to not restart when it finishes.
    timer1.AutoReset = false;

    timer1.Start();
}

 void timerTick(object o, ElapsedEventArgs ea)
 {
     if (browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("stop it!");
     }
 }
```